# Summing iteration to calculate "bottom" for stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created list of lists:

```
 list2=[[0,0,0,0,0]]
max_el=5
for i in range(max_el):
    list2.append([])
```

The first list has 5 nulls.
I have also a dictionary with a lot of key elements and each key element has a list with 5 values.
What I want to do is  that each next list of list2 summs the values of previous list with dictionary values.
Example:

```
dic={"A":[1,1,1,1,1],"B":[4,4,4,4,4],"C":[2,2,2,2,2],"D":[2,2,2,2,2],"E":[2,2,2,2,2]}
```

I have this code:

```
for bar in range(0,max_el):
    list1=list2
    for value,oldvalue in zip(dic,list1[bar]):
        num=dic[value][bar]
        suma=oldvalue+num

        list1[bar+1].append(suma)

    list2=list1
```

Which gives me:

```
list2=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 4, 2, 2, 2], [2, 8, 4, 4, 4], [3, 12, 6, 6, 6], [4, 16, 8, 8, 8], [5, 20, 10, 10, 10]]
```

The problem is this takes to long when I have a lot of  data. How can I write this more efficiently ?
(I'm using this to calculate the "bottom", for my stacked bar chart)

Comment: Use numpy arrays instead of lists? Then you can just sum the arrays and avoid the iteration

Comment: @tom could you make an example code please? Im not so familiar with numpy